# Provide a real time scenario to draw a bubble chart for blog publishing

Tags: charts, visualization, bubble-chart

I planned to publish a blog related to the chart control development (Data visualization).
Particularly I want to plot a Bubble chart
Any one suggest real time for this blog.

Need a real time example for bubble series in MAUI or WPF to publish a blog